# How can I encode/decode a string to Base64 in Swift?

Tags: swift, base64

I want to convert a string to Base64. I found answers in several places, but it does not work anymore in Swift. I am using Xcode 6.2. I believe the answer might be work in previous Xcode versions and not Xcode 6.2.

Could someone please guide me to do this in Xcode 6.2?

The answer I found was this, but it does not work in my version of Xcode:

```
var str = "iOS Developer Tips encoded in Base64"
println("Original: \(str)")

// UTF 8 str from original
// NSData! type returned (optional)
let utf8str = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

// Base64 encode UTF 8 string
// fromRaw(0) is equivalent to objc 'base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0'
// Notice the unwrapping given the NSData! optional
// NSString! returned (optional)
let base64Encoded = utf8str.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.fromRaw(0)!)
println("Encoded:  \(base64Encoded)")

// Base64 Decode (go back the other way)
// Notice the unwrapping given the NSString! optional
// NSData returned
let data = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64Encoded, options:   NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.fromRaw(0)!)

// Convert back to a string
let base64Decoded = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
println("Decoded:  \(base64Decoded)")
```

ref: http://iosdevelopertips.com/swift-code/base64-encode-decode-swift.html

Comment: Swift extension is clean and handy. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46969102/1996294

Answer (score 104, accepted):

I don’t have 6.2 installed but I don’t think 6.3 is any different in this regard:

`dataUsingEncoding` returns an optional, so you need to unwrap that.

`NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.fromRaw` has been replaced with `NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue:)`.  Slightly surprisingly, this is not a failable initializer so you don’t need to unwrap it.

But since `NSData(base64EncodedString:)` *is* a failable initializer, you need to unwrap that.

Btw, all these changes were suggested by Xcode migrator (click the error message in the gutter and it has a “fix-it” suggestion).

Final code, rewritten to avoid force-unwraps, looks like this:

```
import Foundation

let str = "iOS Developer Tips encoded in Base64"
println("Original: \(str)")

let utf8str = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

if let base64Encoded = utf8str?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0)) 
{

    println("Encoded:  \(base64Encoded)")

    if let base64Decoded = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64Encoded, options:   NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
                          .map({ NSString(data: $0, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) })
    {
        // Convert back to a string
        println("Decoded:  \(base64Decoded)")
    }
}
```

(if using Swift 1.2 you could use multiple if-lets instead of the map)

**Swift 5 Update:**

```
import Foundation

let str = "iOS Developer Tips encoded in Base64"
print("Original: \(str)")

let utf8str = str.data(using: .utf8)

if let base64Encoded = utf8str?.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0)) {
    print("Encoded: \(base64Encoded)")

    if let base64Decoded = Data(base64Encoded: base64Encoded, options: Data.Base64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    .map({ String(data: $0, encoding: .utf8) }) {
        // Convert back to a string
        print("Decoded: \(base64Decoded ?? "")")
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just do `[]` instead of `NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0)`?

Comment: Yes, you can; I just tested it. `[]` is the default value, so you can just call the function without passing in any parameters: `utf8str?.base64EncodedString()`

Answer (score 281):

**Swift**

```
import Foundation

extension String {

    func fromBase64() -> String? {
        guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: self) else {
            return nil
        }

        return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    }

    func toBase64() -> String {
        return Data(self.utf8).base64EncodedString()
    }

}
```

Comment: This is in secure code, you need to handle optionals.

Comment: Added Swift 3 Syntax

Comment: I tried converting this base 64 string: `dfYcSGpvBqyzvkAXkdbHDA==` and expected output had to be: `u�Hjo���@���` but the function above returns nil. You can check the above base-64 string's output on these sites: [Site1](http://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html), [Site2](http://www.utilities-online.info/base64/#.WG6glbFh2Rs)

Comment: @ZaidPathan, fixed!

Answer (score 31):

**Swift 4.2**

```
"abcd1234".data(using: .utf8)?.base64EncodedString()
```

Answer (score 29):

**Xcode 11.4 • Swift 5.2 or later**

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var data: Data { Data(utf8) }
    var base64Encoded: Data { data.base64EncodedData() }
    var base64Decoded: Data? { Data(base64Encoded: string) }
}
```

---

```
extension LosslessStringConvertible {
    var string: String { .init(self) }
}
```

---

```
extension Sequence where Element == UInt8 {
    var data: Data { .init(self) }
    var base64Decoded: Data? { Data(base64Encoded: data) }
    var string: String? { String(bytes: self, encoding: .utf8) }
}
```

---

```
let original = "iOS Developer Tips encoded in Base64"

let utf8Data = original.data                             // 36 bytes
let base64EncodedString = utf8Data.base64EncodedString() //  aU9TIERldmVsb3BlciBUaXBzIGVuY29kZWQgaW4gQmFzZTY0\n"
let base64EncodedData = utf8Data.base64EncodedData()     //  48 bytes"

print("base64EncodedData:", original.base64Encoded)      //  48 bytes
print("base64EncodedString:", original.base64Encoded.string ?? "") // "aU9TIERldmVsb3BlciBUaXBzIGVuY29kZWQgaW4gQmFzZTY0"
print("base64DecodedData:", original.base64Encoded.string?.base64Decoded  ?? "") // 36 bytes
print("base64DecodedString:", original.base64Encoded.base64Decoded?.string ?? "") // iOS Developer Tips encoded in Base64
```

Answer (score 23):

You could just do a simple extension like:

```
import UIKit

// MARK: - Mixed string utils and helpers
extension String {


    /**
    Encode a String to Base64

    :returns: 
    */
    func toBase64()->String{

        let data = self.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        return data!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

    }

}
```

iOS 7 and up

Answer (score 21):

**Swift 4.0.3**

```
import UIKit

extension String {

func fromBase64() -> String? {
    guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: self, options: Data.Base64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0)) else {
        return nil
    }

    return String(data: data as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
}

func toBase64() -> String? {
    guard let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
        return nil
    }

    return data.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using same code but still, complier gives error: Value of type 'Data' has no member 'base64EncodedStringWithOptions' in Swift 4.0.3

Comment: With `Data(self.utf8).base64EncodedString()` no optional would be needed for toBase64(). From below answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35360697/129202

Answer (score 14):

After thorough research I found the solution

Encoding

```
    let plainData = (plainString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let base64String =plainData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.fromRaw(0)!)
    println(base64String) // bXkgcGxhbmkgdGV4dA==
```

Decoding

```
    let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options:NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.fromRaw(0)!)
    let decodedString = NSString(data: decodedData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)    
    println(decodedString) // my plain data
```

More on this http://creativecoefficient.net/swift/encoding-and-decoding-base64/

Answer (score 14):

Swift 3 or 4

```
let base64Encoded = Data("original string".utf8).base64EncodedString()
```

Comment: Best answer on the page because it is updated, returns a non optional, and doesn’t wrap such simple operation in an extension.

Answer (score 14):

**Swift 5.1**, **Xcode 11**:

```
public extension String {

    /// Assuming the current string is base64 encoded, this property returns a String
    /// initialized by converting the current string into Unicode characters, encoded to
    /// utf8. If the current string is not base64 encoded, nil is returned instead.
    var base64Decoded: String? {
        guard let base64 = Data(base64Encoded: self) else { return nil }
        let utf8 = String(data: base64, encoding: .utf8)
        return utf8
    }

    /// Returns a base64 representation of the current string, or nil if the
    /// operation fails.
    var base64Encoded: String? {
        let utf8 = self.data(using: .utf8)
        let base64 = utf8?.base64EncodedString()
        return base64
    }

}
```

Comment: This works great, is really succinct code and helped immensely.

Comment: No need to return an optional from `base64Encoded `. You can simply return `Data(utf8).base64EncodedString()`

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 3 / 4 / 5.1**

Here is a simple `String` extension, allowing for preserving optionals in the event of an error when decoding.

```
extension String {
    /// Encode a String to Base64
    func toBase64() -> String {
        return Data(self.utf8).base64EncodedString()
    }

    /// Decode a String from Base64. Returns nil if unsuccessful.
    func fromBase64() -> String? {
        guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: self) else { return nil }
        return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let testString = "A test string."

let encoded = testString.toBase64() // "QSB0ZXN0IHN0cmluZy4="

guard let decoded = encoded.fromBase64() // "A test string."
    else { return }
```

Answer (score 2):

After all struggle I did like this.

```
func conversion(str:NSString)
{

    if let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: str as String, options:NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0)),
        let decodedString = NSString(data: decodedData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {

        print(decodedString)//Here we are getting decoded string
```

After I am calling another function for converting decoded string to dictionary

```
        self .convertStringToDictionary(decodedString as String)
    }


}//function close
```

//for string to dictionary

```
func convertStringToDictionary(text: String) -> [String:AnyObject]? {
    if let data = text.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]

            print(json)
            if let stack = json!["cid"]  //getting key value here
            {
                customerID = stack as! String
                print(customerID)
            }

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**FOR SWIFT 3.0**

```
let str = "iOS Developer Tips encoded in Base64"
print("Original: \(str)")

let utf8str = str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

if let base64Encoded = utf8str?.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
{

  print("Encoded:  \(base64Encoded)")

  if let base64Decoded = NSData(base64Encoded: base64Encoded, options:   NSData.Base64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    .map({ NSString(data: $0 as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) })
  {
    // Convert back to a string
    print("Decoded:  \(base64Decoded)!")
  }
}
```

Comment: It always returns me nil. Can you please help.

Answer (score 2):

```
public extension String{
    ///base64EncodedString
    var base64EncodedString:String{
        if let data = data(using: .utf8){
            return data.base64EncodedString()
        }
        return ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 2):

A short example of converting Data to String:

```
import Foundation

let base64EncodedString = "SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ=="

if let data = Data(base64Encoded: base64EncodedString) {
  if let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
    print(str)  // Output: "Hello, World!"
  }
}
```

This code first creates a **Data** object from the base64-encoded string using the **Data(base64Encoded:)** initializer. Then it creates a string from the data object using the String(data:encoding:) initializer.

Note that the **Data(base64Encoded:)** and **String(data:encoding:)** initializers can both throw errors, so it's a good idea to wrap the code in a do-catch block to handle any potential errors.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.2

```
var base64String = "my fancy string".data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)?.base64EncodedString()
```

to decode, see (from https://gist.github.com/stinger/a8a0381a57b4ac530dd029458273f31a)

```
//: # Swift 3: Base64 encoding and decoding
import Foundation

extension String {
//: ### Base64 encoding a string
    func base64Encoded() -> String? {
        if let data = self.data(using: .utf8) {
            return data.base64EncodedString()
        }
        return nil
    }

//: ### Base64 decoding a string
    func base64Decoded() -> String? {
        if let data = Data(base64Encoded: self) {
            return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
var str = "Hello, playground"
print("Original string: \"\(str)\"")

if let base64Str = str.base64Encoded() {
    print("Base64 encoded string: \"\(base64Str)\"")
    if let trs = base64Str.base64Decoded() {
        print("Base64 decoded string: \"\(trs)\"")
        print("Check if base64 decoded string equals the original string: \(str == trs)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[SwiftyBase64](https://github.com/drichardson/SwiftyBase64) (full disclosure: I wrote it) is a native Swift Base64 encoding (no decoding library. With it, you can encode standard Base64:

```
let bytesToEncode : [UInt8] = [1,2,3]
let base64EncodedString = SwiftyBase64.EncodeString(bytesToEncode)
```

or URL and Filename Safe Base64:

```
let bytesToEncode : [UInt8] = [1,2,3]
let base64EncodedString = SwiftyBase64.EncodeString(bytesToEncode, alphabet:.URLAndFilenameSafe)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Airspeed Velocity answer in Swift 2.0:

```
let str = "iOS Developer Tips encoded in Base64"
print("Original: \(str)")
let base64Encoded = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
print("Encoded: \(base64Encoded)")
let base64DecodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64Encoded, options: [])!
var base64DecodedString = String(data: base64DecodedData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
print("Decoded: \(base64DecodedString)")
```