# Equivalent Java function Base64.encode(byte, 0) in Swift

Tags: java, swift

I have the following function in Java(write inside an Android app)

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(stringPath);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); // bm is the bitmap object  era quality 100
byte[] byteData = baos.toByteArray();
byte[] newB = Base64.encode(byteData,0);
```

It get an Image file and convert it to a byte array.

I need that to work on Swift.

I was able to convert the byteData to Int8, the equivalent of byte array in Swift.

I use the code below:

```
let filename = "RES4010110001"
let test_image:UIImage = UIImage(named: filename)!
let dataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(test_image, 1)! as Data
var bytes: [Int8] = dataImage.map{Int8(bitPattern: $0)}
```

When I print this data using print(bytes) I got the same results on iOS and Android when I compare the "byteData" from Android and "bytes" from iOS

But I don't know what is the Java equivalent function below on Swift

```
Base64.encode(byteData,0);
```

How can I create an equivalent function on Swift of the function above?

For me, it appears that this function is encoding a byte array. But I have no idea of how I can encode a Int8 Array.

I said Int8 because for me, Int8 is the Swift equivalent of byte type in Java.

edit: I want to encode a Int8 array, I guess this is what the Java function (the function in the post title) is doing inside the Android app.

Comment: Don't try to encode the Int array -- encode the `Data` from `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` like I pointed you towards in the last question you asked about this.

Comment: This data that I want to convert is needed to create a JSON file to be send to a Java Server. What you suggests is that I convert using "dataImage.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions.lineLength64Characters)" and after that convert it to NSData and then finally to Int8 array, is that correct?

Comment: Edit: I need the data in this format [-1, -40, -1, -32, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, ...], A String(base64 or not) is not an option, because the server only accepts data as a Java byte[]. I expect that I was able to explain my situation.

Comment: Your question asked for a base 64 encoding, so I assumed that's what you wanted. An array of Ints is not a base 64 encoding.

Comment: Sorry if my question title is confuse. I was talking about a Base64 encoding function on Java. The function on the title is running inside an Android app. I want to convert this function to run on iOS. This function is capable to encode a byte array. That's is what I was looking for. On Swift, the equivalent of Java byte array is an Int8 array. I want to encode a Int8 array.

Comment: Okay, so if I'm following correctly (which I'm not entirely sure I am), what happened when you tried the method mentioned in the 2nd comment here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46969102/2970947

Comment: @ElliottFrisch This didn't work for me because I don't want to encode a String, I want to encode an Int8 array.

Comment: @jnpdx I try to use the method in the 2nd comment. It create a different Int8 array, but the function is not equivalent to the Java Base64.encode function.

Comment: Rule 0 of translating code (and natural languages too): do not translate _literally_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find an definite answer using part of the answer created by
@Sweeper and from another answer published here on Stackoverflow

```
let filename = "RES4010110001"
let test_image:UIImage = UIImage(named: filename)!
let dataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(test_image, 1)! as Data // use apenas este que é correto, o galvez usa jpg no android
let dataImageStringBase64:String = dataImage.base64EncodedString(options: [.lineLength76Characters])
let byteArray = [UInt8](dataImageStringBase64.utf8)
```

The answer posted by @Sweeper just miss this line

```
let byteArray = [UInt8](dataImageStringBase64.utf8)
```

This last line of code made the code works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`base64EncodedData`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/2142925-base64encodeddata) to encode your `Data` to get an encoded `Data`, rather than working with `[Int8]`.

The Java code passes `0` (`DEFAULT`) as the `flags`. According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64#encode(byte%5B%5D,%20int)), this means it's compliant with RFC 2045. RFC 2045 says that lines should be no more than 76 characters, so we should pass `lineLength76Characters`. RFC 2045 also requires CRLF as line endings, but `base64EncodedData` seems to insert them automatically even if we don't pass `endLineWithCarriageReturn` and `endLineWithLineFeed`.

```
let filename = "RES4010110001"
if let testImage = UIImage(named: filename),
    let dataImage = testImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1) {
    let encodedData = dataImage.base64EncodedData(options: [.lineLength76Characters])
} else {
    // failed to get the UIImage, or the JPEG data, handle the error here...
}
```

I suggest that you do not work with `[Int8]` here. The `byte[]`s in the Java code are clearly not just "lists of numbers between -128 and 127". They represent *data buffers*, and those are represented by the `Data` struct in Swift. Don't worry, Both `Data` and `[Int8]` share a very similar set of protocol conformances, like `MutableCollection`, `RangeReplaceableCollection`, `RandomAccessCollection` etc. You can do almost everything you can do to an `Int8` array, to a `Data`.