# Swift 3: Converting Data to String returns a nil value

Tags: swift

Converting Data to String returns a nil value.

Code:

```
// thus unwraps the image
if let image = image{
        print("Saving image data")

    // don't unwrap here
        if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image){ 
            let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)

            print(str)

        }
    }
```

I don't know the reason. 
Also, how do I convert the String back to Data?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? You shouldn't ever need to convert image data to a string

Comment: Also you're using if let wrong. Let me edit...

Comment: I am using EVReflection. I want to be able to json my classes. But data is creating a problem.

Comment: Basically, I just want an easy way to store my classes into SQLite. Any things close to Gson for swift?

Comment: You should be able to store binary data into sqlite. Shouldn't need to convert it to string.

Comment: Can you not just store the image data in a SQLite blob?

Comment: I really don't want to write a whole scheme. I really want to do this : object.toJsonString() using EVReflection. Then simply save it.

Comment: Can I store CLPlacemark as a blob too?

Comment: @BillyJeans You should likely use the `NSCoding` api for serialization in swift/objc.

Comment: So if I NSCoding my classes, I can store it as a BLOB?

Comment: Do the answers help at:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29365145/how-to-encode-string-to-base64-in-swift

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This doesn't work because when you interpret the bytes of the Image as a String, the string is invalid. Not every jumble of data is a valid utf8 string. i.e. not every collection of n bits (8, sometimes 16) are a valid utf8 code point. The Swift String api loops through the data object you pass it to validate that it is a valid string. In your case, theres no reason to think that this Data is a valid string, so it doesn't work.

A good read on utf8:
https://www.objc.io/issues/9-strings/unicode/

Comment: You better use `base64` encoding to convert `Data` to `String`.

Comment: How do I use base64 @Ryan

Comment: base 64 is a bad solution for this kind of thing.

Comment: Strings store readable text, where readable text is defined as a data conforming to a specification/encoding (like utf8/16, ascii, etc). Your image data obviously doesn't fit that definition.

Comment: images also do not belong in sqlite. base64 blows up the size by quite a bit leading to significant inefficiency, and databases (esp. sqlite) aren't designed to store blobs of unstructured data, they're designed to store tabular data.

Comment: It is a bad solution. But this app isn't for commercial reasons.  It is for my homework. The professor does not care how I do it.

Comment: haha, understood... but the string api does care. I've tried this before, and I don't think there's any string encoding you can choose that will work in all cases.

Comment: Now That I have been developing for a while, I should have taken Ryan answer. The assignment was for school and base64 always does the trick. I hate stackoverflow because everyone over complicated everything.