# How do I get a byte array from base64 in swift 3?

Tags: swift, base64, byte, decode

I'm translating an Android application to iOS with swift 3. My problem is with the next block of Java code:

```
String b64 = "KJT-AAAhtAvQ";
byte[] bytesCodigo = Base64.decode(b64, Base64.URL_SAFE);
System.out.Println(bytesCodigo.length) // 9
```

How would it be in swift?

Thanks

Comment: Did you see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29365145/how-to-encode-string-to-base64-in-swift ?

Comment: You generally don't want arrays of bytes. That's what `Data` is *for*

Answer (score 11):

One would just create a `Data` (`NSData` in Objective-C) from the base64 string. Note, though, that the standard `Data(base64Encoded:)` does not have “URL Safe” rendition, but you can create one that replaces “-” with “+” and “_” with “/” before trying to convert it:

```swift
extension Data {
    init?(base64EncodedURLSafe string: String, options: Base64DecodingOptions = []) {
        let string = string
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "+")
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: "/")

        self.init(base64Encoded: string, options: options)
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```swift
guard let data = Data(base64EncodedURLSafe: string) else { 
    // handle errors in decoding base64 string here
    return 
}

// use `data` here
```

Obviously, if it was not a “URL safe” base64 string, you could simply do:

```swift
guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: string) else { 
    // handle errors in decoding base64 string here
    return 
}

// use `data` here
```

---

You asked how one gets a “byte array”: `Data` effectively is that, insofar as the `Data` type conforms to the `RandomAccessCollection` protocol, just as the `Array` type does. So, you have many of the “array” sort of behaviors should you need them, e.g.:

```swift
for byte in data {
    // do something with `byte`, a `UInt8` value
}
```

or

```swift
let hexString = data.map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }
    .joined(separator: " ")

print(hexString)                        // 28 94 fe 00 00 21 b4 0b d0
```

So, in essence, you generally do not need a “byte array” as `Data` provides all the sort of access to the bytes that you might need. Besides, most Swift APIs handling binary data expect `Data` types, anyway.

---

If you literally need an `[UInt8]` array, you can create one:

```swift
let bytes = data.map { $0 }
```

But it is generally inefficient to create a separate array of bytes (especially when the binary payload is large) when the `Data` provides all the array behaviors that one would generally need, and more.