# how to create GIF from base64 string in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, base64, animated-gif

I am getting base64 string with extension and I want to convert base64 string to GIF and display it in ImageView. I am using iOSDevCenters+GIF.swift file. I am getting NSData from string but when data converted in image, its giving nil.Below is my code:

```
let imageData = profileImageString.data(using: .utf8)
self.thumbnailMedia.image = UIImage.gifImageWithData(imageData!)
```

Does anybody have any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Are you getting a string inside a json api or are you getting just the gif data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are starting from a base64 string, you should decode it as a base64 string not `UTF8`.

```
if let data = Data(base64Encoded: imageDataString) {
    let image = UIImage(data: data)
}
```

This snippet simply takes the encode image string, decode into a `Data` object and create an image from the data.
If you are working a lot using base64 string I strongly suggest you to extend the `String` structure functionalities.

```
extension String {
    //: ### Base64 encoding a string
    func base64Encoded() -> String? {
        if let data = self.data(using: .utf8) {
            return data.base64EncodedString()
        }
        return nil
    }

    //: ### Base64 decoding a string
    func base64Decoded() -> String? {
        if let data = Data(base64Encoded: self) {
            return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

This snippet was taken from [Github](https://gist.github.com/stinger/a8a0381a57b4ac530dd029458273f31a), credits to Stringer.

Also another way is use the [extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29365145/how-to-encode-string-to-base64-in-swift/43817935#43817935) created by Leo Dabus that is compliant with Swift convention:

```
extension String {
    var data:          Data  { return Data(utf8) }
    var base64Encoded: Data  { return data.base64EncodedData() }
    var base64Decoded: Data? { return Data(base64Encoded: self) }
}

extension Data {
    var string: String? { return String(data: self, encoding: .utf8) }
}
```

Comment: no need to unwrap your data when converting your string to utf8 data. It will never fail

Comment: You can just use `Data(.utf8).base64EncodedString()` and remove optional from the return type

Comment: Also your methods don't have any parameters so you should make them computed properties check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29365145/how-to-encode-string-to-base64-in-swift/43817935#43817935

Comment: didn't know about it, but could you clarify it seems that the method data(using:) returns an optional. I'm using them in playground and they seems to work.

Comment: `Data(utf8)` I added a dot by mistake

Comment: All strings in Swift are unicode (utf8). So you are not converting anything. It will never fail