# Compressing string with zlib using Swift on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, compression, zlib

My iOS app fetches compressed data from the backend and then decompresses it into a human-readable string. This is the function I use for decompression:

```swift
import Compression

func decompress(_ data: Data) -> String? {
  guard let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8),
        let data = Data(base64Encoded: string)
  else { return nil }
  let headerSize = 2
  let size = compression_decode_scratch_buffer_size(COMPRESSION_ZLIB)
  let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: size)
  defer { buffer.deallocate() }
  let result = data.subdata(in: headerSize..<data.count).withUnsafeBytes {
    guard let baseAddress = $0.baseAddress else {
      return ""
    }
    let decompressedSize = compression_decode_buffer(
      buffer,
      size,
      baseAddress.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: 1),
      data.count - headerSize,
      nil,
      COMPRESSION_ZLIB
    )
    guard decompressedSize > 0 else {
      return ""
    }
    return String(
      decoding: Data(bytes: buffer, count: decompressedSize),
      as: UTF8.self
    )
  } as String
  guard !result.isEmpty else {
    return nil
  }
  return result
}
```

I need a reverse function, that returns compressed data for a given uncompressed string:

```swift
func compress(_ string: String) -> Data?
```

I'm struggling with the implementation. Here is what I've tried:

```swift
import Compression

func compress(_ string: String) -> Data? {
  guard let data = string.data(using: .utf8) else {
    return nil
  }
  let bufferSize = data.count + data.count / 2 + 12
  var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: bufferSize)
  let compressedSize = data.withUnsafeBytes {
    guard let baseAddress = $0.baseAddress else {
      return 0
    }
    return compression_encode_buffer(
      &buffer,
      buffer.count,
      baseAddress.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self),
      data.count,
      nil,
      COMPRESSION_ZLIB
    )
  }
  guard compressedSize > 0 else {
    return nil
  }
  return Data(bytes: buffer, count: compressedSize)
}
```

While it does compress the string, it's not a reverse operation to the `decompress` function that I use:

```swift
let string = "Hello, World!"
let compressedData = compress(string)! // Data(74 bytes)
let decompressedString = decompress(compressedData) // nil
```

The `decompress` function is proven to work fine given the data returned by the backend. I'm using Swift 5.8 and target iOS 16.

Thanks in advance for any hints and suggestions.

---

#### Update 1.

After investigating the problem, it occurred to me that the functions can be simplified. I can remove the base64 string conversion and operate just on raw `Data` types.

I made it to work with the following implementation:

```swift
import Foundation
import Compression

func compress(_ data: Data) -> Data? {
  var buffer = [UInt8](
    repeating: 0,
    count: compression_encode_scratch_buffer_size(COMPRESSION_ZLIB)
  )
  let compressedSize = data.withUnsafeBytes {
    guard let baseAddress = $0.baseAddress else {
      return 0
    }
    return compression_encode_buffer(
      &buffer,
      buffer.count,
      baseAddress.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self),
      data.count,
      nil,
      COMPRESSION_ZLIB
    )
  }
  guard compressedSize > 0 else {
    return nil
  }
  return Data(bytes: buffer, count: compressedSize)
}

func decompress(_ data: Data) -> Data? {
  let headerSize = 0
  var buffer = [UInt8](
    repeating: 0,
    count: compression_decode_scratch_buffer_size(COMPRESSION_ZLIB)
  )
  let subdata = data.subdata(in: headerSize..<data.count)
  let decompressedSize = subdata.withUnsafeBytes { sourcePtr in
    guard let baseAddress = sourcePtr.baseAddress else {
      return 0
    }
    return compression_decode_buffer(
      &buffer,
      buffer.count,
      baseAddress.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self),
      subdata.count,
      nil,
      COMPRESSION_ZLIB
    )
  }
  guard decompressedSize > 0 else {
    return nil
  }
  return Data(bytes: buffer, count: decompressedSize)
}
```

It works for the following example:

```swift
let string = "Hello, World!"
let compressed = compress(string.data(using: .utf8)!)!
let decompressed = decompress(compressed)!
let decompressedString = String(data: decompressed, encoding: .utf8)
decompressedString == string // ✅ true
```

However, this won't work with the data the backend is returning to me. In order to make it work, I need to change the `headerSize` value to `2` in the `decompress` function. When I do so, I can decompress data from the backend, but my `compress` function is no longer working correctly. I don't really understand what is the header size, and how to update the `compress` function so it's symmetrical to my `decompress` function with `headerSize` equal `2`.

Comment: It looks like the decompressor is expecting Base64-encoded data, whereas your compressor is not Base64 encoding.

Comment: @MarkAdler thanks for the hint. It may be the issue. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Several answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29365145/how-can-i-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-swift